# Transcription of baptism record handwriting

Tags: london, transcriptions

I am having trouble deciphering some of this baptism record.

It seems to be a match for a William John Gifford, whose parents were William and Lydia, servants in Belgravia. I think there's a small note saying he was born two years earlier "Born the 20th Day of October 1841"? as this is for 23rd October 1843. And the address is something like No 15, West Pound Street?, or Millpond Street? in Kensington/Chelsea, London.

The church was Holy Trinity Brompton ( [map](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Holy+Trinity+Brompton/@51.4975962,-0.171277,17.18z) )

So my three questions are:

1. What does it say under "William John"?
2. what was their Abode?
3. Is the mother's name Lydia?

[image]

From mid-right of this page, for more context:

[image]

London Metropolitan Archives; London, England; Reference Number: p84/tri2/003

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, the text under "*William John*" is **Born the 20(?)th day of October 1841** (the second digit of the date is a little unclear).
2. The address is **No 5(?) *Rutland Street*** (again, the house number is unclear in that image).
3. Yes, the mother's name is **Lydia**.

---

You should be able to confirm the date of birth by obtaining a copy of William John Gifford's birth certificate from the GRO (these are now available in pdf form).

You may be able to check the address in a street directory from the early 1840s.  The Guildhall Library and the London Metropolitan Archives both have extensive collections of directories for London.

Alternatively, the University of Leicester has a project where they have been digitising some [Historical Directories of England & Wales](http://specialcollections.le.ac.uk/digital/collection/p16445coll4), although I'm not sure how good their coverage is for London/Middlesex at that period.  Finally, Ancestry (and some of the other genealogy sites) have begun to add historical directories to their collections, so it's probably also worth checking those, although the last time I looked, their coverage was also not great.

Comment: Great thanks. There's a Rutland St. half way between that church and where they previously lived in Belgravia so that seems very likely. Yes I will buy the cert now, often it also has the address too. I didn't know about the Guildhall records, thanks for that and the other tips.

Comment: FYI. The 1841 Post Office Directory at Leicester lists Rutland Gate but not the Street, presumably as they are smaller servants houses.